# Lattice of congruences of a lattice is algebraic

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I'm trying to understand some basics of the lattice theory and I would like to know how one can prove that **given any lattice *L* the (complete) lattice of all congruences on *L* is an algebraic lattice**.

I know the "increasing chain" charecterisation of the join operation in the lattice of congruences on a lattice, but I don't know how to apply it.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use these facts:

1. every congruence $\theta$ of $\mathbf{L}$,
   $$\theta = \bigcup_{\langle a, b \rangle \in \theta} \Theta(a,b) = \bigvee_{\langle a, b \rangle \in \theta} \Theta(a,b),$$
   where $\Theta(a,b)$ is the least congruence of $\mathbf{L}$ that contains the pair $\langle a, b \rangle$.
2. a compact congruence of $\mathbf{L}$ is a finitely generated one.

Perhaps you still have to prove this last fact, but it is not difficult; the first one is trivial.

Comment: Or even easier, replace 2. with the following: **every principal congruence is compact** This will be enough.